# Why do doctors reccommend vegetable oils in high cholesterol and cardiovascular disease?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, bioinformatics

As there is high cholesterol in body why the patient need more fats and why the doctors are recommending it[image]

Transcribed:

> Vegetable oils are rich in polyunsaturated fatty acids (PUFA). The fatty acids present in such oils have more than one double bonds. Doctors recommend such oils to patients suffering from high blood cholesterol or cardiovascular diseases. This helps in lowering the cholesterol level in blood. When vegetable oils are hydrogenated, the unsaturated fatty acids become saturated and the oil changes to solid fat (vanaspati and margarine).

Comment: source please it will improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

The subtext of the textbook excerpt quoted above is that when people are eating vegetable oil, they are not eating other fat sources. Saturated fats increase LDL levels, and unsaturated fats do not.

A C Beynen, M B Katan, [**Why do polyunsaturated fatty acids lower serum cholesterol?**](https://doi.org/10.1093/ajcn/42.3.560), *The American Journal of Clinical Nutrition*, Volume 42, Issue 3, September 1985, Pages 560–563.

> Replacement of saturated by polyunsaturated fatty acids in the diet may lower serum very low-density and low-density lipoprotein concentrations because the liver preferentially converts polyunsaturated fatty acids into ketone bodies instead of into very low-density lipoprotein triglycerides. Thus unlike saturated fatty acids, polyunsaturated fatty acids are transported to the tissues for oxidation without leaving a trail of lipoprotein remnants in the form of low-density lipoproteins.